# Make the `\ddots` looks well in a transformed matrix

Tags: math-mode, positioning, matrices

I want to typeset a large matrix:

[image]

```
\addtocounter{MaxMatrixCols}{8}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
 &\ddots\\
 &      &1\\
 &      & &0& &      & &1& &      &\\
 &      & & &1&      & & & &      &\\
 &      & & & &\ddots& & & &      &\\
 &      & & & &      &1& & &      &\\
 &      & &1& &      & &0& &      &\\
 &      & & & &      & & &1&      &\\
 &      & & & &      & & & &\ddots&\\
 &      & & & &      & & & &      &1
\end{pmatrix}
```

I had to change the `\arraycolsep` so as to fit for paper width:

```
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
```

and then the `\ddots` in the matrix look a bit ugly:

[image]

So I changed the `\arraystretch`

```
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
```

the dots all are too low and has not a conspicuous improvement:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use commands of the `graphicx` package for rotating and raising the dots, such as `\rotatebox` and `\raisebox`. Define a macro for it, preferably also macros for the value. So you could easily adjust it if necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\dotsangle}{-12}
\newcommand{\dotsxshift}{.2ex}
\newcommand{\dotsyshift}{1ex}
\newcommand{\rdots}{\hspace{\dotsxshift}%
    \raisebox{\dotsyshift}{\rotatebox{\dotsangle}{$\ddots$}}}
 \begin{document}
\addtocounter{MaxMatrixCols}{8}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
 &\rdots\\
 &      &1\\
 &      & &0& &      & &1& &      &\\
 &      & & &1&      & & & &      &\\
 &      & & & &\rdots& & & &      &\\
 &      & & & &      &1& & &      &\\
 &      & &1& &      & &0& &      &\\
 &      & & & &      & & &1&      &\\
 &      & & & &      & & & &\rdots&\\
 &      & & & &      & & & &      &1
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix]